Saving Checklist function so it holds its state
I have a Checklist which allows points to get ticked (via toggle true/false).
This works but when you swap the view it obviously resets, so I did try to save the state of the View via @AppStorage but I am not sure how to do it.
I was trying to use the isChecked variable but this causes a problem in my ChecklistSection struct where it does say

"Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected argument type 'Bool'".

I am not sure how to fix convert the value.
changing @Binding var isChecked: Bool to @AppStorage("isChecked) var isChecked: Bool = false leads to above explained issue
changing @Binding var items: [(String, Bool)] to @AppStorage("Items") var items: [(String, Bool)] leads to

"No exact matches in call to initializer"

Google did not help me with it, I found a similar question where binding could not convert to binding.bool but the solutions there did not work for me (but it in a .wrappedValue and .constant(false))
I was reading the Apple Document but its super short and did not help me unfortunately.
import swiftUI

struct ChecklistItem: View {
    
    let text: String
    
   
    @Binding var isChecked: Bool. 
//@AppStorage("isChecked") var isChecked: Bool = false
    
    // definition of HStackView
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(text)
            Spacer()
            Toggle(isOn: $isChecked, label: {
                Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.circle" : "circlebadge")
            })
            .toggleStyle(.button)
            .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
            .tint(isChecked ? .green : .red)
            .background(isChecked ? Color.green : Color.red)
        }
    }
}

struct ChecklistSection: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var items: [(String, Bool)]
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text(title)) {
            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                ChecklistItem(text: items[index].0, isChecked: $items[index].1) //this is where the error is shown
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChecklistView: View { 
    
    
    // Initial Scene Assesment Items
    @State private var initialItems: [(String, Bool)] = [
        ("Scene Safety", false),
        ("Mechanism of Injury", false),
        ("Number of Patients recognised?", false),
        ("Additional Resources requested?", false),
        ("Catastrophic Haem/C-Spine", false)
    ]
    {** more Items like the above**}
    
    
    // Sections
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ChecklistSection(title: "Initial", items: $initialItems)
                {**Other ChecklistSection blocks**}
    
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChecklistView()
    }
}


Saving the value in ChecklistItem makes no sense, because you have multiple items with multiple different isChecked values. I recommend to use a struct rather than a tuple as data model and save items as JSON or property list to disk. I suppose the user will be able to add and remove items so it's a good practice to save the entire array anyway. The benefit of a struct is also to get rid of iterating over the indices in ForEach which is – on the other hand – a bad practice.

Thank you first of all for your replay. I am quite new to this and I tried the last couple of hours how to do it instead, unfortunately I could not figure a way out. Do you have an example or a more detailed description what I should do instead. Only if its not to much work for you.
